# Undo a delivery n clearcase?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

is there a way to UNDO a Clearcase delivery after it has been completed? I saw a post that was close but it was still being delivered.

I want to undo a delivery thqt has been completed (if possible); it was delivered from child stream to parent and I do not want it there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a deliver has been completed, all the versions created during said deliver are recorded in a special UCM activity beginning with `deliver.xxx`.

You can try the [cSet.pl perl script](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/05/0927_bellagio/) in order to undo the deliver activity.
It will create new versions which will cancel the versions just created by the deliver.

```
 ccperl cset.pl -undo deliver.xxxx
```